# Apache2 RewriteRule does not work

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, apache2

I configured my apache2 like this before:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ...
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  !=on
    RewriteRule "^/?(.*)" "https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1"    # HTTPS auto redirect
    RewriteRule "^/example/?$" "/example.json"
    ...
```

When I access `example.com/example` or `example.com/example/` it does shows the contents of `example.com/example.json`.

Then I installed another software and it requires to access `/software/web` for the main webpage, and directories other than `web` shouldn't be exposed to the public. So I write this:

```
# DocumentRoot is /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html/software/>
    Require all denied
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/software/web/>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

It works by accessing `example.com/software/web`. I want to rewrite the link to omit the `/web` part (so I can just type `example.com/software`), so I tried to add this:

```
RewriteRule "^/software/?$" "/software/web"
```

However when I tried to access the shortened URL it give out a 403 error:

```
You don't have permission to access /software/ on this server.
```

I tried to add a trailing slash like this:

```
RewriteRule "^/software/?$" "/software/web/"
```

Then it says

```
You don't have permission to access /software/app.php on this server.
```

I tried several tweaks to the regex but no good. How to make it work? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have another RewriteRule somewhere in your config that is rewriting `/software/` to `/software/app.php`. Since `/software/app.php` doesn't match the regex you've written, it never gets applied.

You will probably want to move this rewrite earlier in your config, before the one that adds the `app.php`. You may also want to add the `[L]` flag after the rewrite if you don't want any further rewrites to be applied after the `/web/` one.

Comment: It seems like there is an `.htaccess` file under `/software/web`, which has some redirection like `RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]`. I placed my RewriteRules under `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`, is that the problem? Also I tried to change to `RewriteRule "^/software/?$" "/software/web/app.php" [L]`, but it just jumps to `/` when I access `/software`. It's really confusing and I wonder what happened here.

Comment: Finally after some tinkering I remembered that the RedirectRule has another flag called `PT` before, and after adding it does work, although I didn't use anything like `Alias` or `Redirect`. The working RewriteRule looks like this: `RewriteRule "^/software/?$" "/software/web" [PT]`